# BIRT Repeating only part of a header

Tags: birt

What I am currently trying to do in BIRT 4.5 is repeat only a specific part of my tables header. However when I set it to repeat the header it always repeats the entire header.

Is there a way to only repeat a specific part of the header?

In my example - there is two headers, the "table name" and the "column headings". I only want the column headings to repeat. I have a feeling its likely going to be a scripted fix, but have no idea where to go to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might get tricky because headers can be repeated for groups but also for pagebreaks.

Not the most fancy, but you should get something working by defining a global variable on the page script

```
var headerCount = 0;
```

Then select an element in the header, open the onPrepare script and have it increment the counter:

```
headerCount = headerCount + 1;
```

with this information, you can make true/false statements in the visibility property.

Each object has onPrepare, onCreate, onRender and onPagebreak scripts. Not sure what the exact difference, so you have to experiment a bit with this. (because when an element should increase the counter, but is not rendered due to the visibility clause, you can get unexpected results.)

Good luck!